# Hospital Setting. "Flag" a patient if a result has a specific value

Tags: sql-server

Coding in SQL Server 2008

I have a list of patients and associated result values.
I need to filter patients based on a specific result value (MMRC) being null or not null. Each patient has multiple results, but only one needs to be evaluated for this.

Example:

```
Patient SMITH 
Result Value 1
Result Value 2
Result Value 3
MMRC = 2

Patient JONES
Result Value 1
Result Value 2
Result Value 3
MMRC = NULL
```

I want to "flag" Patient SMITH as "Pulmonary" (MMRC is not null) and Patient JONES as "Cardiac" (MMRC is null) so that I can use that "Flag" as a parameter in my crystal report.

Comment: Please, add table schema and your actual code to help us to find a solution.

Comment: sounds like you need to look up conditional aggregation

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MMRC IS NULL 
            THEN 'Cardiac'
            ELSE 'Pulmonary'
       END condition
FROM Patient
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a bunch :)